# How do I open a jsp page as a popup via a spring controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I am working on a website which accepts user name and password through a jsp page which opens as a popup from the home page. The details are sent to a java spring controller which authenticates the user. If the credentials are incorrect, I want to display an error message in the same login page (inside a div tag), with the login page opening as a popup. I am using jsp:include to open the login jsp page as a popup when the user clicks on the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ajax for submitting form then you need to send JSON or String response from controller.

```
@ResponseBody
public String login(HttpServlet request,HttpServletResponse){
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

  //do operation for authenticate user from database, I am assuming User Bean
  User user     = userDao.authenticate(username,password);
  if(user!=null){

    return "success";
  }else{

   return "error";
  }

}
```

and if you are using normal form submit you can easily set some values to map and then on jsp page check using JSTL and show popup which you want to show.

```
@ResponseBody
    public String login(HttpServlet request,HttpServletResponse,Map map){
      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");

      //do operation for authenticate user from database, I am assuming User Bean
      User user     = userDao.authenticate(username,password);
      if(user!=null){

        map.put("error",0);
      }else{

      map.put("error",1);
      }
     return "home";

    }
```

in jsp you can check it using  to show your popup.

Comment: I am actually submitting the form using just the regular submit button, although I'm willing to use it if it solves my problem. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Then use second code which I have listed set some value on map and then check it on jsp using JSTL and write jquery to show popup.